# Discord.py оповещения с YouTube

Tags: python, youtube, discord, discord.py, discord-api

***Хочу сделать Дискорд бота который будет оповещать о новых видео на том или ином канале*** *(как mee6)*. ***В документации ничего не нашёл, буду очень благодарен если кто-то мне поможет.***

Comment: Разделите задачу на: 1) получение информации о новых видео 2) оповещение от бота discord

Comment: попробуй написать парсер для ютуба